# Remove last comma from serialized array.join(', ')?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to remove the last comma in the array. For example, `self.committed.join(', ').titleize` produces "Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat,".

I don't know if the answer is somehow removing the empty `""` at the end of the array `["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", ""]` so that way I can use `to_sentence` and it won't come out looking like this "Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, And"

Or if there is a way with `join` to prevent the additional comma?

**model**

```
serialize :committed, Array
```

**db**

```
t.text     "committed",       default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
```

I don't want to change `serialize` or the `db`, but I'm open to it as a last resort.

Comment: You seem to approach this from the wrong end. Your string contains a trailing comma just because the array contains an empty string. So the actual problem is not `join`, but your array content. You should figure out where this extra `""` comes from and eliminate it. Maybe add a validation to your model to disallow empty array values (or restrict them to abbreviated weekdays). BTW, the YAML database default does _not_ contain the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why the array has an empty string as the last element, but it's easy to skip it:

```
self.committed[0..-2].to_sentence.titleize
```

Or:

```
self.committed.reject(&:blank?).to_sentence.titleize
```

The latter will skip all blank elements, whereas the former will skip the last element regardless of its content.

If you want to individually capitalize the words before calling `to_sentence` (to avoid "and" being capitalized), just use `map`:

```
self.committed[0..-2].map(&:titleize).to_sentence
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jordan I don't know why either, weird! Your removed the last comma, but now it titleize the word "And" too. You know how to create an exception for "And"?